# how to get element ID on console after click the search button,using jquery

Tags: jquery

what is the method to get element id on console on click the search button, i,e? I want to know from which ID search call came? and that ID wants to show on console? help me with code

Comment: Without your html, we can only give you some code, and there is no guaranty that it will work.

Comment: No clue i can really know what you do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not check like that. However you can add `debugger;` or `alert("Hi button 1 called");`  on button click event.

Comment: First, this seems more like a comment rather than an answer, second, the OP is asking for a way to show the Id of a button that is clicked in the console. So yes it can be checked like that,.

Answer (score 1):

Hoe this is what you are looking for, use `attr('id')` to get the id of a specific element

```js
$('.btn1').click(function(e){

   console.log($(this).attr('id'))

})

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div nid="1" class="par1">
  <i class="fa fa-search" xid="300"></i>
  <div>
    <h3>some heading</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p>Hello</p>
      <button class="btn1" id="a1">Click</button>
      <button class="btn1"  id="a2">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1" id="a1">Click</button>
<button class="btn1"  id="a2">Click</button>
<button class="btn1" id="a3">Click</button>
```

Comment: @ChPujithaRajesh pls approve it if it works , thanks

Comment: but  btn is there in parent div,while clicking the button ID is coming on console,but where ever iam clicking to div elements console is showing id,

Comment: how to share code in stackflow

Comment: change the class name of those buttons

Comment: create snipet , by which you can share

Comment: @ChPujithaRajesh just update your question by clicking on edit